# Visual studio freeze and duplicate <br /> issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, formatting

I have a web application (ASP.Net) and I am using VS2010 for implementation. Sometimes my VS hangs up/freezes and by the time it unfreeze it would have reformatted my aspx code and it would duplicate every `<br />` tag I have, here is a snippit:

**Before**

```
<b>District:</b>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblARDist"></asp:Label>
<br />
<br />
```

**After it unfreeze**

```
<b>District:</b>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblARDist"></asp:Label>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

This is very annoying because unlike the other formatting issues (e.g. adding white spaces, putting multiple statements in one line) the VS formatting tool **cannot do** anything about it. I have to manually remove all of the duplicates! I am on the verge of writing my own tool/add-on to fix this stupid glitch in my code

Any thoughts or ideas to why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you address the "freeze" issue as well. Why is it "freezing"? Look at Task Manager and see what's running on your system at the time.

Comment: @JohnSaunders the freeze is from VS2010, my guess is that after is because its running the formatting at the wrong time, memory and CPU consumption are both normal but still it freeze because its doing something

Comment: when I say something I am talking a behavior like a deadloop.. sometimes I would force it to shut down and when I open it up again I would have the extra `<br />` and other formatting problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening is in Visual Studio when you type in for exemple `<div>` it create automaticly the `</div>` associate with it.

So what is happening is while VisualStudio froze it tried to close every `<br />` you type with a matching `<br />`, thus replicating every `<br />` on your page.

To resolve the issue try turning off the autocomplete feature in VisualS

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `<br/>` is self-closing. Are you suggesting that Visual Studio doesn't _know_ that?

Comment: Yep! That is exactly what I am saying. There might be a bug where VS doesnt recognise `<br />` as being self closed. Or maybe someone else used This particular VS and setup Intellisence to close all `<br />`.

Comment: It seems unlikely that VS doesn't recognize basic HTML syntax.

Comment: @Sebastien this is an interesting thought.. I checked the `Text Editor-> HTML -> Formatting->Tag Specific Options` and didnt find anything for `<br />` so I added one.. will keep an eye on it and see if this solves the problem..thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @JohnSaunders yea I totally agree with you, but at this point I am willing to try any ideas thrown at me. VS has many formatting issues, so what Sebastien had said might be true, everything is possible with MS

Comment: @Sebastien since I made this change it didnt happen again! I think I will submit a bug report to MS

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that intellisense may be trying to be overactive for all intents and purposes. You could disable it, but you'd be doing yourself a disservice. Instead your best bet is to deal with it, and remove the extra tags on occasion.